# Confidence interval of transformed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, confidence-interval

Let $X$ be a Normal random variable of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Also let $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be a positive strictly increasing bijective function.

I would like to find the **symmetric** 0.95 "confidence interval" of $g(X)$ centred by its mean, that is, find $a$ such that

$$
\mathbb{P}\big(z - a \leq g(X) \leq z + a\big)=0.95,
$$

where $z = \mathbb{E}[g(X)]$ is the mean. Suppose that such interval exists.

However, I failed to compute the interval in closed-form. Observe that

$$
\mathbb{P}\big(z - a \leq g(X) \leq z + a\big) = \mathbb{P}\big(g^{-1}(z - a) \leq X \leq g^{-1}(z + a)\big),
$$

so essentially, we want to find the $a$ by solving

$$
\mathrm{CDF}(g^{-1}(z + a)) - \mathrm{CDF}(g^{-1}(z - a)) = 0.95,
$$

where $\mathrm{CDF}$ is the CDF of $X$. But how to find a **closed-form solution/approximation** to this equation? By "approximation", I mean an analogy of $\mu \pm 1.96\sigma$ for $\approx0.95$ of Normal.

Comment: Your observation implicitly assumes that $\ g\ $ is increasing.  However, bijectivity of $\ g\ $ is insufficient to guarantee that.  In general,
$$
\mathbb{P}\big( z-a\le g(X)\le z+a\big)=\mathbb{P}\big(X\in g^{-1}\big([z-a,z+a]
\big)\big)\ ,
$$
but $\ g^{-1}\big([z-a,z+a]\big)\ $ is not even necessarily *an interval*, let alone the interval $\ \big[g^{-1}(z-a),g^{-1}(z+a)\big] \ $.

Comment: *If $\ g\ $ is continuous*, it must be *either* strictly increasing *or* strictly decreasing, but if it's the latter, you get
$$
\mathbb{P}\big( z-a\le g(X)\le z+a\big)=\mathbb{P}\big(g^{-1}(z+a)\le X\le g^{-1}(z-a)\big)\ ,
$$
rather than your identity.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Indeed, it's hard to verify there exists such $a$ when $g$ is only known bijective. I have now corrected the question as per your suggestion.